# Knockout observable updates reflected only in inner scope

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

I'm trying to update an `Observable` from within an `Ajax` callback using...

```
function LocaleVM() {
    const self = this;
    self.Language = ko.observable("en");
    self.Strings= ko.observable();
    self.toggleLanguage = function () {
        const lang = self.Language() === 'en' ? 'es' : 'en';
        console.log(self.Language());
        console.log(lang);
        $.ajax({
            url: `/${lang}`,
            method: 'GET',
            success: function (data, textStatus, xhr) {
                self.Language(lang);
                console.log(self.Language());
                console.log(lang);
                //===============================================
                ... update strings ...
            },
            error: function (xhr, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                console.log(errorThrown);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

And that is the console output every time `toggleLanguage` gets called...

```
en
es
es
es
```

Which seems to be updating fine within the call back but not outside. What seems to be the problem here?

Comment: i think its because u are using `const lang` doesnt `const` imply that it cant be reassigned  afterwards? maybe try to replace `const` with `var` and see if it helps

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you're never actually updating the value of the `Language` observable.

Here is a condensed version of your script...

```
self.toggleLanguage = function () {
    const lang = self.Language() === 'en' ? 'es' : 'en';
    $.ajax({
        url: `/${lang}`,
        method: 'GET',
        success: function (data, textStatus, xhr) {
            self.Language(lang);       //  <<<  THIS IS ALWAYS THE SAME VALUE.
            console.log(self.Language());
            console.log(lang);
        }
    });
}
```

I can only assume the values you're fetching in that AJAX request but don't you want something like this?

```
self.toggleLanguage = function () {
    $.ajax({
        url: `/${lang}`,
        method: 'GET',
        success: function (data, textStatus, xhr) {
            self.Language(data);       //  <<<  USE THE NEWLY-FETCHED VALUE.
            console.log("Previous value: " + lang);
            console.log("Current value: " + self.Language());
        }
    });
}
```